# Como mudar os tipos de dados nos campos em uma tabela no mysql de uma vez

Tags: mysql, table

Estou com a seguinte tabela:

```
 create table pessoas(
 id tinyint,
 nome char,
 peso float,
 altura float(3),
 sexo int(1),
 nacionalidade varchar (20)
 );
```

Porém quero alterar todos os campos de uma vez

```
alter table pessoas modify nome varchar (20) not null;
alter table pessoas modify peso decimal(5,3);
alter table pessoas modify sexo enum ('M','F');
```

Enfim, tem como mudar para um comando apenas as "`modify`"?

Comment: O que você quer é armazenar essa palavra "Modify" em uma variavel ? para mudar uma unica palavra e todos os outros recebrem ela ?

Answer (score 3):

### Tem sim.

O padrão SQL define uma mudança só a cada `ALTER TABLE`, mas o MySQL estendeu o padrão para permitir esta sintaxe:

```
ALTER TABLE PESSOAS MODIFY
   nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   peso DECIMAL(5,3),
   sexo ENUM('M','F')
;
```

Você pode até mudar a ordem das colunas, com `AFTER` ou `BEFORE`, por exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE PESSOAS MODIFY
   nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   peso DECIMAL(5,3),
   sexo ENUM('M','F') AFTER nome
;
```

Neste último exemplo, além de mudar os tipos, a ordem das colunas passará a ser `nome`,`sexo` e `peso`.

No manual tem mais detalhes:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

E o trecho que mais interessa para o que foi perguntado é este aqui:

> *Multiple ADD, ALTER, DROP, and CHANGE clauses are permitted in a single ALTER TABLE statement, separated by commas. This is a MySQL extension to standard SQL, which permits only one of each clause per ALTER TABLE statement. For example, to drop multiple columns in a single statement, do this:*
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE t2 DROP COLUMN c, DROP COLUMN d;
> ```

Que quer dizer mais ou menos isso:

> São permitidas várias cláusulas ADD, ALTER, DROP, and CHANGE em um único comando ALTER TABLE, separadas por vírgulas. Isto é uma extensão do MySQL em relação ao padrão SQL, que permite só uma alteração por comando ALTER TABLE statement. Por exemplo, para remover várias colunas num comando só, fica desta forma:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE t2 DROP COLUMN c, DROP COLUMN d;
> ```

Comment: As constraint `  add constraint pk_pessoas primary key(id);` segue o mesmo raciocínio :?

Comment: @alexoaboab se tiver alguma dificuldade, faça um http://sqlfiddle.com com o create e o alter em seguida e deixe um comentário com o link pra gente conferir. Em principio, qualquer coisa com o ALTER que não tenha conflito pode ser acumulada na mesma operação, seja ADD, ALTER, DROP e CHANGE.